# not able to serialize scala class using genson

Tags: java, json, scala, json4s, genson

I have a problem where i can't get `toJson` to work with Scala classes. It outputs an empty json string. : `{}`

The classes have their member variables populated. 
I tried both a custom genson class and the default genson class. Both yield the same output. 
Case classes work fine, though.

Am i doing something wrong? Code and output below

I have a few classes that look like this :

```
    package gensontest
    import com.owlike.genson.annotation.JsonProperty
    class Person (@JsonProperty("name") var name:String ,@JsonProperty("age") var age:Int,@JsonProperty("address") var address: Address) extends Serializable{

    }

    package gensontest

    import com.owlike.genson.annotation.JsonProperty

    class Address (@JsonProperty("building") var building:Int, @JsonProperty("city") var city:String) extends Serializable{

    }

package gensontest

import com.owlike.genson._
import com.owlike.genson.ext.json4s._
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.JsonDSL._
import org.json4s.JsonAST._

object CustomGenson {
    val customGenson = new ScalaGenson(
      new GensonBuilder().useConstructorWithArguments(true).withBundle(ScalaBundle(),Json4SBundle()).create()
    )


}
```

And then a object that houses main()

```
package gensontest
import CustomGenson.customGenson._
//import com.owlike.genson.defaultGenson._
import org.json4s._
/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */
object App{
  def main(args: Array[String]) : Unit = {
    case class Addresscc(street: String, building: Int)
    case class Personcc(name: String, age: Int, address: Option[Address1])
    case class Usercc(uId: Int)

    var someAddr = new Address(157,"Paris")
    var someone:Person = new Person("Eugen",28,someAddr)
    val json = toJson(Personcc("foo bar", 28, Some(Addresscc("rue des lapins", 1337))))
    val userInstance = new User(2)
    val userInstance1 = new Usercc(2)

    //check if Person's members are public
    println(someone.name)
    println(someone.age)
    println(someone.address.building)
    println(someone.address.city)
    val personS = toJson(someone)
    val addressS = toJson(someAddr)
    val userInstanceS = toJson(userInstance)
    val userInstanceSCC = toJson(userInstance1)

    println(personS)
    println(addressS)
    println(userInstanceS)
    println(json)
    println(userInstanceSCC)
    var p1:Person1 = fromJson[Person1](json)
    var p:Person = fromJson[Person](personS)
  }
}
```

The output is:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_141.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java "-javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=64224:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_141.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_141.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_141.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_141.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_141.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_141.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_141.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_141.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_141.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_141.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_141.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_141.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_141.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_141.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_141.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_141.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_141.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_141.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_141.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_141.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_141.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_141.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ant-javafx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_141.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/dt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_141.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/javafx-mx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_141.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jconsole.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_141.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/packager.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_141.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/sa-jdi.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_141.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar:/Users/kartiku/IdeaProjects/gensontestscala1/target/classes:/Users/kartiku/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-library/jars/scala-library-2.11.8.jar:/Users/kartiku/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-reflect/jars/scala-reflect-2.11.8.jar:/Users/kartiku/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-library/srcs/scala-library-2.11.8-sources.jar:/Users/kartiku/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-reflect/srcs/scala-reflect-2.11.8-sources.jar:/Users/kartiku/.m2/repository/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.11.8/scala-library-2.11.8.jar:/Users/kartiku/.m2/repository/org/json4s/json4s-core_2.11/3.5.0/json4s-core_2.11-3.5.0.jar:/Users/kartiku/.m2/repository/org/json4s/json4s-ast_2.11/3.5.0/json4s-ast_2.11-3.5.0.jar:/Users/kartiku/.m2/repository/org/json4s/json4s-scalap_2.11/3.5.0/json4s-scalap_2.11-3.5.0.jar:/Users/kartiku/.m2/repository/com/thoughtworks/paranamer/paranamer/2.8/paranamer-2.8.jar:/Users/kartiku/.m2/repository/org/scala-lang/modules/scala-xml_2.11/1.0.6/scala-xml_2.11-1.0.6.jar:/Users/kartiku/.m2/repository/com/owlike/genson-scala_2.11/1.4/genson-scala_2.11-1.4.jar:/Users/kartiku/.m2/repository/com/owlike/genson/1.4/genson-1.4.jar:/Users/kartiku/.m2/repository/org/scala-lang/scala-reflect/2.11.0/scala-reflect-2.11.0.jar gensontest.App
objc[54099]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_141.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_141.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Eugen
28
157
Paris
{}
{}
{}
{"address":{"building":1337,"street":"rue des lapins"},"age":28,"name":"foo bar"}
{"uId":2}

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: this is what my pom looks like:
```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.owlike</groupId>
      <artifactId>genson-scala_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you posted all the actual code but with the latest version it works fine so far for me (note that you don
t need the JsonProperty annotation here).

```
import com.owlike.genson._
import com.owlike.genson.annotation.JsonProperty

class Pers(var f: Int, @JsonProperty("b") var b: Int)

object Test extends App {
  val genson = new ScalaGenson(new GensonBuilder().withBundle(ScalaBundle()).create())
  println(genson.toJson(new Pers(1, 2)))
}
```

Try running the example above.

Comment: Hi Eugen,Sorry for the late reply. recently got back to this project. Tried this in a separate class and same result, both with and without the custom genson behavior.

Comment: '''package gensontest

import com.owlike.genson.defaultGenson._

class EugenPers(var f: Int, var b: Int)

object EugenTest {
  def main(args: Array[String]) : Unit = {
    //val genson = new ScalaGenson(new GensonBuilder().withBundle(ScalaBundle()).create())
    println(toJson(new EugenPers(1, 2)))
  }
}'''